# How do I load Tor-Browser with Wayland?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, fedora

Firefox functions in Fedora/CentOS with Wayland, Tor-Browser should too. No Xorg necessary. How do I launch Tor-Browser under Wayland? Thank you!

Comment: What problem are you having when you try to launch it?

Comment: There is no native wayland tor launcher to launch torbrowser; so it loads in xorg; there is a native wayland launcher for firefox, which tor is based on, it should be available for tor also, or easy to accomplish